# Java music player progressBar

Tags: java, swing, jframe, javasound, jprogressbar

I was trying to create a simple music player only for become more fluent to use swing components. Whatsoever, I am stuck a just like this. It has no compiler or runtime error, rather creates a window as I intend. But whenever I pause the music and try to continue, progress bar doesn't work anymore and window basically doesn't respond till I terminate the program. (Yet clip starts to play again.) Only progressBar, tenBack and play buttons created yet, as you can see that repetitive `while`'s are meant to simulate the progression of the playing `clip`.
Which first one is working as I intended but second one messes up the execution. I have been trying to solve it myself for hours, and still don't have much of an idea if it's even an error. I also tried to take the second `while` at the very end of `actionPerformed` method, and creating a whole another method as progressor.
However problem remain the same. Thanks for any assistance.

```
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JProgressBar progressBar;
    JButton tenBack;
    JButton play;
    Image icon;
    Clip clip;
    File musicFile;
    
    MyFrame() throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException{

        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon("icon.png");

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setTitle("Music Player");
        this.setSize(420, 200);

        musicFile=new File("pigstep.wav");

        AudioInputStream audioStream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicFile);
        clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioStream);
        clip.start();

        progressBar=new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380,20));
        progressBar.setBackground(Color.white);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        tenBack=new JButton("<<");
        tenBack.addActionListener(this);
        tenBack.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,30));

        play=new JButton("||");
        play.addActionListener(this);
        play.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,30));

        this.add(progressBar);
        this.add(tenBack);
        this.add(play);
        this.setVisible(true);

        while(clip.isRunning()){
            progressBar.setValue((int)(100*clip.getMicrosecondPosition()/clip.getMicrosecondLength()));
            progressBar.setString((int)(clip.getMicrosecondPosition()/(1e6*60))+":"+(int)((clip.getMicrosecondPosition()/1e6)%60)+" / "+(int)(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/(1e6*60))+":"+(int)((clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1e6)%60));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==tenBack)
            clip.setMicrosecondPosition((long)(clip.getMicrosecondPosition()-1e7));
        else if(e.getSource()==play){
            if(clip.isRunning()){
                play.setText(">");
                clip.stop();
            }
            else{
                play.setText("||");
                clip.start();
                while(clip.isRunning()){
            progressBar.setValue((int)(100*clip.getMicrosecondPosition()/clip.getMicrosecondLength()));
            progressBar.setString((int)(clip.getMicrosecondPosition()/(1e6*60))+":"+(int)((clip.getMicrosecondPosition()/1e6)%60)+" / "+(int)(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/(1e6*60))+":"+(int)((clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1e6)%60));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `while(clip.isRunning())` loop is stopping Swing’s event dispatch thread from processing any events.  Remove that loop, and replace it with a [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) (*not* java.util.Timer!).

Comment: Much obliged. I'll try it out.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter *"a blocking call"* Nope!